# LINQ connection in app.config

Tags: .net, linq, connection

I have been reading how to store the connection string for a dbml in the app.config whereby I would create a partial class with the same name as the existing one for the dbml.
One thing I haven't seen though, should this be created within the dbml's designer.cs file?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoNoNoNo!

If you add it there, it will be overwritten next time you open the *.dbml file.

Create a new file.  Labeling the class "partial" will allow the two class definitions to be merged during the compile.